# how to allow all users to do a sign in with google account

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-api-js-client

so i created an angular project in which i have button google sign in . the problem is that i must allow the user to connect by adding he's address email in  Google API Console so my question is how can i allow the access to all user and know if the user has signed up before or not !!
the following code is

```
<button (click)="signIn()" *ngIf="user == null">GOOGLE SIGNIN</button>
<button (click)="signOut()" *ngIf="user != null"> GOOGLE SIGNOUT</button>
<div *ngIf="user !=null">
  <div> Full Name: {{user.getBasicProfile().getName()}} </div>
  <div> Given Name: {{user.getBasicProfile().getGivenName()}} </div>
  <div> Family Name: {{user.getBasicProfile().getFamilyName()}} </div>
  <!-- <div> Image URL:{{user.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl()}} </div> -->
  <img src={{user.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl()}}>
  <div> Email: {{user.getBasicProfile().getEmail()}} </div>
```

so in app.component.html i get the information of the user i want to add also an information if it's a new user or not how can do it

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://fireship.io/lessons/angularfire-google-oauth/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement sign in with google in Angular you have to follow given steps:

1. Create a google app in google cloud console platform and generate a client id.
2. Create a new angular application.
3. Implement login with google using google OAuth 2.0 protocol.

You can read my article on Codingvila [Angular 14 Login with Google using OAuth 2.0](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) where I explained everything step by step with example.

You can also [download](https://www.codingvila.com/2022/07/angular-14-login-with-google-using-oauth.html) the sample example for your practice.